# Composite index with WHERE and GROUP BY

Tags: index, group-by

For this query:

```
SELECT * FROM dogs WHERE a = ? AND b = ? GROUP BY c
```

Which is the better composite index:

```
INDEX(a, b, c)
```

or

```
INDEX(c, a, b)
```

Comment: Have you tried both to see which one performs better? That said, a where clause is executed before a group by. So, consider that.

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. Your pseudo statement isn't valid, as you would have to have an aggregation and a column instead of an asterisk. Something along the line of `SELECT COUNT(*), c FROM dogs WHERE a = ? AND b = ? GROUP BY c;`.

Answer (score 5):

You would normally want either the first index

```
INDEX(a, b, c)
```

or a similar one

```
INDEX(b, a, c)
```

This is because the `a` and `b` columns can then be seeked (reading only the exact necessary rows), and the results will still be sorted by `c`, which means the `GROUP BY` does not need a supporting sort.

---

While the other option

```
INDEX(c, a, b)
```

means that although the data may be sorted by `c`, it requires reading *all* rows and verifying whether they match the `a` and `b` conditions.

---

You probably also want to add `INCLUDE` columns, if your RDBMS supports it, in order to support the rest of the `SELECT` columns.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is difficult to say without having more details on the data and data distribution. In addition to great answer by [Charlieface](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/220697/charlieface) and comment made by [Brendan McCaffrey](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/240213/brendan-mccaffrey), I would like to say that it depends on data selectivity.

If any of the column in a or b narrows down your result set to less than 1% and the other column filters it further down then first column followed by second column is fine - even the reverse order wouldn't matter as long as it is equality operator.

Story gets different when inequality operator comes into play

Let's take an example from StackoverFlow database:

```
select * from Users where Reputation = 1  and  Location = 'Switzerland'
```

Here, I would check selectivity first using below commands:

```
select * from Users where Reputation = 1 -- 6044557 rows
select * from Users where Location = 'Switzerland' -- 4723 rows
```

So, if we create index only on Location column, that itself would be great and logical reads will come down from 142,000 to 14498:

[image]

What if we amend this index and add Reputation in the index:

[image]

Logical read comes down to 5447. Even if you change the order of columns in the index, logical reads remain same.

**Let me cover just one example for inequality operator.**

Index is defined as:
CREATE INDEX Combined ON Users(Location, Reputation)

Logical read is at 9065

[image]

What if we change the order of column in index and redefine as:
CREATE INDEX Combined ON Users(Reputation, Location)

Logical read will change to 17839:

[image]

So, it doesn't matter much as long as it is equality operator and all these conditions filter rows in progressive way - meaning with first condition, row count is reduced to 1000 from 1 million, with second condition, row count reduces further to 500 and so on.

For using group by, you need to use aggregate functions.

Hope this helps.